# Problema para enviar dados do PHP para o banco de dados

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Estou começando com PHP e estou com problema para enviar para o banco de dados, infelizmente não consigo encontrar o erro, se alguém puder ajudar, grato.

O HTML está assim:

```
<form method="post" action="blog.php"  >    
                    <input style="font-family:'open sans',sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#212121"type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Título" required />
                        <br>
                    <input type="text" name="texto" placeholder="Texto"  required />
                        <br>
                    <input style="background-color:red;color:white" type="submit" name="submit" value="enviar" />
                </form>
```

E o PHP assim:

```
<?php
$titulo = $_POST ['titulo'];
$texto = $_POST ['texto'];
$imagem = "imagem";
echo "$titulo";

$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "blog");

mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO postagens (titulo,texto,imagem) VALUES ('$titulo','$texto,'$imagem')");

echo "Sucesso";
?>
```

O nome do banco é 'Blog' e da tabela 'postagens'.

Comment: Quais os textos que aparecem na tela? Dá alguma mensagem de erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// verificação do metodo post
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" )
{
    // obtendo os dados do form
        $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
        $texto  = $_POST['texto'];
        $imagem = "imagem";
        echo "Título: ".$titulo." <br />";

    // realizando a conexão
        $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "blog");
        $query   = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO postagens(titulo,texto,imagem) VALUES ('$titulo','$texto','$imagem')");

    // se executar a query
        if ($query)
        {
            echo "Sucesso";

        }else
        {
            echo "[ERRO]: ".mysqli_connect_error($conexao);
        }
}
?>
```

Veja se isto resolve o teu problema.

Comment: Cara, resolveu sim, valeu mesmo!

Comment: @Alisson fico feliz que tenha resolvido seu problema, marque a resposta como correta para ajudar próximos usuários com o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Está faltando uma aspas simples depois de $texto na query, tente colocar pra ver se funciona

```
mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO postagens (titulo,texto,imagem) VALUES ('$titulo','$texto','$imagem')");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$titulo = $_POST ['titulo'];
$texto = $_POST ['texto'];

$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "blog");

echo "Sucesso";

mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO postagens (titulo,texto) VALUES ("{$titulo}","{$texto}"));
```

Tente essa *query*, ela deve funcionar, mas tire a imagem inicialmente, porque pra fazer o *upload* da imagem você precisará fazer alterações tanto no seu HTML quanto no PHP.

Comment: E por quê acha que assim funcionará? O PHP consegue interpretar as variáveis dentro de uma *string* definida por aspas duplas; as chaves são necessárias apenas com expressões. Aliás, você quebrou a sua *string* ao utilizar aspas duplas dentro da mesma, o que geraria erro de sintaxe. E o campo de imagem está com um valor constante, então não vejo, por enquanto, alguma relação com o problema.

Comment: Na verdade eu não acho que vai funcionar. Sempre faço assim e funciona.